# Basic C-style string copy

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to do a C-style string copy but something is not working right.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main() {
    char string_a[20]="Good day!";
    char string_b[30]="Hi!";
    int i=0;
    cout << "string a: " << string_a << endl;
    cout << "string b: " << string_b << endl;
    while (*string_a++ = *string_b++) {
        cout << ++i << endl;
    }
    cout << "string a: " << string_a << endl;
    cout << "string b: " << string_b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to add words and phrases in your question body instead of your "workaround."

Comment: Perhaps the title alone would have been enough for this problem... but, not for Stack Overflow.  You could have at least mentioned _why_ it failed.

Comment: Two problems.  You've declared `string_a` and `string_b` as arrays, not pointers.  As such, their addresses are immutable, so `string_a++` and `string_b++` should generate errors.  Also, it's better to write `while ((x=y) != '\0')` to make it clear that you're copying and comparing the result to a null character.  In general, a single `=` as an `if` or `while` condition is a red flag.

Comment: It's very easy to write, for example, `while (var1 = var2)` when you really mean `(while var1 == var2)`.  Worse, this can be extremely difficult to find when you scan your code, because you'll see what you _meant_, rather than what you've written.  I've found that new programmers who are trying to show their proficiency tend to use the simpler `while (var1 = var2)`, while more experienced professionals tend to use `while ((var1 = var2) != 0)`, which is easier to maintain.  Saving a few characters up front may cost hours later, and that's assuming the bug doesn't make it to the field.

Comment: Assuming it is a bug, and assuming it helps to look at that. I don't confuse `=` with `==`. But seeing `!= '\0'` gives me a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do:

```
string_a++
```

if `string_a` is defined as an *array.* That only works for pointers and arrays decay to pointers only in specific circumstances.

If you change:

```
while (*string_a++ = *string_b++) {
    cout << ++i << endl;
}
```

into:

```
char *pa = string_a, *pb = string_b;     // a "specific circumstance" :-)
while (*pa++ = *pb++) {
    cout << ++i << endl;
}
```

then it will work just fine, outputting:

```
string a: Good day!
string b: Hi!
1
2
3
string a: Hi!
string b: Hi!
```

Comment: iirc, arrays are pointers, no? How do you declare an array as mutable pointer?

Comment: @pax: This used to be one of my favorite interview questions.  :-)

Comment: NO, NO, NO, a hundred times, NO :-) Arrays are _not_ pointers. They _decay_ to pointers under certain circumstances but definitely not in the code snippet you have.

Comment: @user1011921: arrays are _groups_ of items and the name is immutable - it always references the group (you can't modify it). Pointers are, well, pointers (I can't think of a better term off the top of my head other than addresses, and that would introduce other complications) to a _single_ item. These pointers _can_ be changed to point to different items such as the second or third item in the afore-mentioned array (`const`-ness notwithstanding, of course).

Comment: @user1011921: not quite. You're getting into the dark recesses of the language specs now :-) There's still a difference between arrays and immutable pointers, one of them being what you'll see if you use `sizeof` on them. With the array `int xyzzy[10]`, the _name_ `xyzzy` refers to the array itself (ten integers). Something like the immutable pointer `int *const plugh = &xyzzy` has the name `plugh` referring to a _pointer_ which points to the single integer at the start of `xyzzy`.